# Right way to do non-recursive make?

Tags: c++, makefile

There seem to be only a handful of resources on creating a non-recursive make system, and in none of the ones I've found can I figure out how to handle my use case. My hierarchy looks like this:

```
project/
project/libA/...
project/libB/...
...
project/appA/...
project/appB/...
```

So maybe `project/appA/makefile` depends on `libA` and `libB` and `project/appB/makefile` depends on `libA`, `libC`, and `libF` or something. I want to be able to `make` in every directory and have that work. I have a recursive solution for this already.

All the resources always define a root `project/makefile` that `include`s all the directories above it. But I need that backwards. Are there any examples in the wild for this? I think ideally I want a given library makefile to look like:

```
include ../../rules.mk

SRC := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
INCDIR := ./include

$(add_build_target)
```

... where the base rules.mk would define `add_build_target` to append the correct rules for the given `SRC` and `INCDIR` to `build`. Is this the correct approach? And how do I actually write `add_build_target` to add the correct targets (.o's for all the .cxx's) - everything I've tried gives me "no rule to make target whatever.o" issues, despite me thinking that I've defined them....

Comment: +1 - try CMake, it's really easy to use!

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth How do you handle special cases with automatically written tools?  With handwritten Makefiles, it is pretty easy: just add the name of your special case and its sources near the end of the file, and paste the shell command producing your special case after this.  The distance with what you actually type in the terminal is minimal.

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald: It's been a long time since I did anything with CMake etc., so I couldn't tell you ;)  What I find offensive about Make is that 40 years on, everyone still has to reinvent basic infrastructure (in a grotesque syntax) every time.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I disagree! Just use make correctly, I'm just giving a _sh**_ on all that stuff (CMake, ant, maven, ...) building on top of it. That just introduces another step of indirection and tends to obfuscate what's really going on in the build process. Sometimes these tools even narrow you, being unable to apply certain things you want to/need to build your artifacts properly. _"Make is that 40 years on"_ Having something for that long time, doesn't mean it's outdated, but rather improved, and well accepted.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - but there is no "using Make properly" (at least, not in the sense of "convention").  If there was, then things like "using non-recursive Make" would be a solved issue, you'd just download the canonical "non-recursive Make" library.  Ditto for things as trivial as calculating header dependencies.  Instead, everyone hacks their own thing together, each with its own set of idiosyncrasies and subtle bugs.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Well, it's somehow similar like asking for which of JScript or C++ are better to solve a particular problem. I can just tell you, that we're going to step back from ant + CMake in favor to build up our own make template build system with the productive stuff at our workplace. I have to admit, that noone besides some enlightened people really want's to touch the templates, but just using them and being able to put your own stuff on top with moderate make skills, is much easier, than learning about 3 different tools :P ...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth There is very good inspiration sources for BSD Make, namely the Makefile infrastructure used to build FreeBSD (and probably the other BSDs) and ports. I think building a full operating system with handwritten Makefiles is quite a poof this is a viable approach and anybody writing a serious set of Makefiles — as I do — should carefully study these examples to build on the 30 years experience that went into them. Also GNU Make is a terrible tool, awful to program and not that nicely documented — at least in comparison with BSD Make.

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald: I haven't used BSD Make, so I can't comment on that.  And I don't dispute that the people who maintain an entire OS probably took a pretty sane approach.  However, I stand by my argument that for a tool that's decades old, there's almost *nothing* in the way of canonical reusable "libraries", just lots of websites each promoting a different set of hacks.

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald I agree the documentation of GNU make lacks, and what you're going to do sometimes looks more like _voodo_ instead of serious science. But I'd never want to miss the power of that _voodo_ anymore in future (I'm just remembering all of the cranky workarounds or infrastructure hacks, that I needed to find/apply for ant or CMake). _@OP_ Eehm sorry, we're discussing here, if it's appropriate to use handwritten makefiles at all, instead of approaching to your particular problems.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I may not be enlightened, but I am certainly entertained.

Comment: @Barry _"... but I am certainly entertained."_ Well, at least something good obtained ;-) .. To get serious: Of course `include` prevents to get make called recursively, and is a commonly agreed approach to do so. Though recursively called makefiles have their valid uses (especially if you want to run them in parallel (--> see `-j` option))

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented and extended ideas from the paper

http://sites.e-advies.nl/nonrecursive-make.html

on multiple occasions in corporate environments, and they work very well, in small or large scale environments.  Basically, there is implemented a "directory stack" there and recursive inclusion.  Like I said, works well for me.  Read this paper, I recommend it.

Comment: The link is 404. Please update it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my non-recursive build system implementation called **prorab**:
https://github.com/cppfw/prorab

It allows to achieve exactly what you want. So, you will have independent `makefile` in each directory `appA, appB, libA, libB,...` and if you `cd` to that directory you'll be able to build the project by just typing `make`. In that makefile you'll be able to include a makefile from another directory and add a dependency for your app binary on library binary. So, that way if you do some changes to the library code and build the app, it will detect that and rebuild the library.
Then it is also possible to have a top-level `makefile` which includes all makefiles from those sub-directories, for building everything.
Let me know if you need help with using **prorab**.